# Checkout successful redirects to empty cart but not using Redis

Tags: magento-1.9, redis, cm-redissession

I am debugging a common problem that I have seen others asking about, losing user session data during a successful order which redirects to an empty cart.

Most solutions I have read about suggest a Redis setting can fix that, by setting the following:

```
<break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>
```

However, I have discovered that my site is using Redis backend cache for config settings but not the Redis session - in my `Cm_RedisSession.xml` I can see: `<active>false</active>`

Further, my `local.xml` does not have a **redis_session** node.

So my question - is there an equivalent set of settings for the out-of-the-box session storage and a setting similar to **'break_after_frontend'**? I've been trying to fix this issue forever, finally felt as if I was on the home straight but it was false dawn it seems!

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one [Magento 2 Session getting reset after placing order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270132/magento-2-session-getting-reset-after-placing-order)

Note: Try first directly in vendor and if its work then create a before plugin for the same

Also, pay attention to cookies and domains getting used by cookies

Happy coding

Comment: I'm not sure how the link in your answer is relevant. It suggests to create an event in the success action to set the session. The problem I have is that the session is already lost when I get to the success action. I think the link is for an entirely different problem.

Comment: Have you tried - the reason I have shared the link is that when you reach the success page if this happens it will redirect you to the cart page. If you tried this and no result then ignore this answer or give down vote if you want. Thanks